# Use variable to reference named binding in an Ecto Query

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to build a function that searches for a term in a field of a given table in a query.

For a query like

```
initial_query = 
  Answer
  |> join(:left, [a], q in assoc(a, :question), as: :question)
  |> join(:left, [a, q], s in assoc(a, :survey), as: :survey)
```

I would like to be able to search in the tables referenced by `:question` and `:survey`.

Now, this code works:

```
initial_query
|> or_where(
  [question: t], #:question hard coded
  fragment(
    "CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?",
    field(t, ^field),
    ^"%#{search_term}%"
  )
)
```

However, I want to have a function that takes the named binding as a parameter, but I can't find a way to do it.

**My attempts:**

```
defp search_field(initial_query, table, field, search_term) do
  initial_query
  |> or_where(
    [{table, t}],
    fragment(
      "CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?",
      field(t, ^field),
      ^"%#{search_term}%"
    )
  )
end
```

Gives the error

> ** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) unbound variable `t` in query. If you are attempting to interpolate a value, use ^var
>       expanding macro: Ecto.Query.or_where/3

when called like this:

```
search_field(initial_query, :question, :text, search_text)
```

and

```
defp search_field(initial_query, table, field, search_term) do
  initial_query
  |> or_where(
    [{^table, t}],
    fragment(
      "CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?",
      field(t, ^field),
      ^"%#{search_term}%"
    )
  )
end
```

Gives

> ** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) binding list should contain only variables or `{as, var}` tuples, got: {^table, t}
>       expanding macro: Ecto.Query.or_where/3

---

Is there a way to use a variable to reference a named binding in an Ecto Query?

Comment: Have you btw tried to pin _t_, as suggested in first error response `[{table, ^t}]`?

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Yes, it gives `(Ecto.Query.CompileError) unbound variable \`t\` in query. If you are attempting to interpolate a value, use ^var`, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the answer to this question seems to be that there isn't a way supported by Ecto to do this. @maartenvanvliet solution works nicely, with the downside of relying on internal implementation.

My solution to this problem was to have the function `search_field` to always search in the last joined table, using the `...` syntax described [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#module-positional-bindings):

```
# Searches for the `search_term` in the `field` in the last joined table in `initial_query`.
defp search_field(initial_query, field, search_term) do
  initial_query
  |> or_where(
    [..., t],
    fragment(
      "CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?",
      field(t, ^field),
      ^"%#{search_term}%"
    )
  )
end
```

So this function would be used like this:

```
Answer
|> join(:left, [a], q in assoc(a, :question), as: :question)
|> search_field(:text, search_text)
|> join(:left, [a, q], s in assoc(a, :survey), as: :survey)
|> search_field(:title, search_text)
```

Which, in my opinion, still reads nicely, with the downside of requiring that we are able to change the `initial_query`.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to retrieve the position of the named binding in the bindings. The named bindings are stored in the `%Ecto.Query{aliases: aliases}` field.

```elixir
def named_binding_position(query, binding) do
  Map.get(query.aliases, binding)
end

def search_field(query, table, field, search_term) do
  position = named_binding_position(query, table)
  query
  |> or_where(
    [{t, position}],
    fragment(
      "CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?",
      field(t, ^field),
      ^"%#{search_term}%"
    )
  )
end
```

We first lookup the position of the named binding in the query.aliases. Then use this position to build the query.

Now, when we call

```elixir
Answer
|> join(:left, [a], q in assoc(a, :question), as: :question)
|> join(:left, [a, q], s in assoc(a, :survey), as: :survey)
|> search_field(:question, :text, "bogus")
```

It should yield something like

```elixir
#Ecto.Query<from a in Answer,
left_join: q in assoc(a, :question), as: :question,
or_where: fragment("CAST(? AS varchar) ILIKE ?", q.text, ^"%bogus%")>
```

Of note is that the `{t, position}` tuples in %Query.aliases to refer to the position of the named binding is an internal implementation and not documented. Therefore, could be subject to change. See https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2832 for more information

Comment: Thanks! Relying on internal implementation is not ideal, but this is a clever solution